# Kafka Streams cannot connect to Zookeeper-less broker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka cluster that runs in Kraft mode using this docker-compose provided by Confluent https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/6.2.0-post/cp-all-in-one-kraft/docker-compose.yml .

I have a MongoDB connector that works as expected but when I try to run a kafka-streams application (outside docker) with the following configuration properties

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "data-feed");
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

I get this error:

```
12:11:53,882 WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient 
[Consumer clientId=data-feed-35a87372-6518-41f5-b89c-3243700abb0e-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=data-feed]
Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Do I need to configure my streams application differently when working in Kraft mode?

Comment: You try to connect to localhost from outside your docker into the docker , there are plenty of question on stack related to how to do so, No need to do diffrent configuration for kraft

Comment: You need to connect to `broker:29092` if the code is running in Docker... (this is unclear from your question)

Comment: @OneCricketeer just edited the question. The application is running outside docker. It seems the problem is in the docker-compose provided by confluent.

Comment: Can you try changing `KAFKA_LISTENERS` to have `PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092'`?

Comment: That works @OneCricketeer. Please add it as an answer. Thanks